# Combine two modules into a single module for publishing

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I'd like to split up a module (`library`) in two modules (`lib-core`) and (`lib-extras`).
Currently, I'm publishing with artifact id `library`, and I want to keep this functionality as well. I also want to publish the two separate modules.

For example:

> - lib-core
>
>   - class A
> - lib-extras
>
>   - class B
> - library
>     *(empty, depends on *lib-core* and *lib-extras*)*

What I want to achieve is when publishing these modules, I get an archive `lib-core` containing class `A`, and archive `lib-extras` containing class `B`, and an archive `library`, containing both classes `A` and `B`.

**Is this possible using gradle?**

This is my uploadArchives task, which is applied in all three modules:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def sonatypeRepositoryUrl
if (isRelease == 'true') {
    sonatypeRepositoryUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
} else {
    sonatypeRepositoryUrl = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    version = VERSION_NAME + '-SNAPSHOT'
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID

                repository(url: sonatypeRepositoryUrl) {
                    authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
                }

                pom.project {
                    name POM_NAME
                    packaging POM_PACKAGING
                    description POM_DESCRIPTION
                    url POM_URL

                    scm {
                        url POM_SCM_URL
                        connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                        developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                    }

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                            url POM_LICENCE_URL
                            distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                        }
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                            name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    signing {
        required { isRelease == 'true' && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
        sign configurations.archives
    }

    task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
        source = android.sourceSets.main.java
    }

    task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'javadoc'
        from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
    }

    task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
    }

    artifacts {
        archives androidSourcesJar
        archives androidJavadocsJar
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it would help anyway check [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push) point 4.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this ?